# A question regarding the existence of a differentiable function with certain simple measure-theoretic properties

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a set $[a, b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty, \infty\}$ and a continuous function $F:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $F^\prime(x) := \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$ exists in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty, \infty\}$ for every $x \in (a, b)$ and $\{F(x): x \in (a, b) \land |F^\prime(x)|= \infty\}$ has positive Lebesgue outer measure?

Comment: The set you're asking about was proved for continuous functions to have Lebesgue measure zero by [Luzin in 1912](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=6531&option_lang=eng). The same result for Lebesgue measurable functions was proved by [C. C. Young in 1916](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s2-15.1.360), and the same result for arbitrary functions was proved by [S. Saks in 1924](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm5/fm5112.pdf). See [Denjoy-Young-Saks Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Saks_theorem).

Comment: I do not think my question follows from the Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem. Indeed the derivative can only be infinite on a null set, but does that imply that the range of the null set under F is a null set as well?

Comment: You're correct, and I overlooked what you were describing. There are various results about such range sets, by [Krishna Murari Garg for example](https://www.google.com/search?q=Garg+denjoy+analogue). I'll look them up later when I have time (I have two notebook binders containing photocopies of every paper published by Garg), unless you can find what you want online with the search I've given.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate that, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E\subset [0,1]$ be compact, nowhere dense, and have positive measure. We don't need the intricacies of Cantor sets for this: Simply choose an open subset $U$ of $(0,1)$ containing $\mathbb Q \cap (0,1),$ of measure less than $1,$ and let $E=[0,1]\setminus U.$

For $x\in \mathbb R,$ let $g(x)= d(x,E).$ Then $g$ is continuous everywhere, $g=0$ on $E,$ and $g>0$ everywhere else. Now define

$$G(x) = \int_0^x g(t)\,dt,\,\, x\in \mathbb R.$$

We have $G\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ with $G'(x)=g(x)$ everywhere.

Claim: $G$ is a strictly increasing bijection of $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R.$ Hence $G$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R.$

Proof: Because $G'=g\ge 0,$ $G$ is at least nondecreasing. If $x<y,$ then $(x,y)\setminus E$ is open and nonempty. This follows from the nowhere density of $E.$ Therefore $G'=g>0$ in an open subset of $(x,y),$ showing $G(x)<G(y)$ as desired. It's easy to verify $G(x)\to  \infty$ as $x\to \infty,$ and $G(x)\to  -\infty$ as $x\to -\infty.$ By the IVT, $G$ is surjective. As is well known, this implies $G$ is a homeomorphism.

Now let $F= G^{-1}$ on $\mathbb R.$ As we know, $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a homeomorpism. By the usual results in calculus, $F'(y)$ exists for $y\in \mathbb R \setminus G(E)$ with the formula

$$F'(y)= \frac{1}{G'(G^{-1}(y))}.$$

Now let $y_0\in G(E).$ We wish to show

$$\tag 1 \lim_{y\to y_0} \frac{F(y)-F(y_0)}{y-y_0}=\infty.$$

There is a unique $x_0$ such that $G(x_0)=y_0.$ Because $G$ is a continuous bijection, $(1)$ holds iff

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{F(G(x))-F(G(x_0))}{G(x)-G(x_0)}=\infty.$$

But the last expression is the same as

$$\frac{x-x_0}{G(x)-G(x_0)}= \frac{1}{\dfrac{G(x)-G(x_0)}{x-x_0}}.$$

Because $G'(x_0)=0,$ the last expression $\to \infty$ as $x\to x_0.$ This gives $(1)$ as desired.

So we have shown $F$ is differentiable everywhere (in the extended sense), with $0<F'<\infty$ on $\mathbb R\setminus G(E)$ and $F'=\infty$ for $y\in G(E).$ Since $\{F(y): F'(y)=\infty\} =E,$ and $E$ has positive measure, we have our example.

Comment: This is beautiful, is this example your own? I will read it a bit more carefully later, but it looks solid. I can award the bounty in 14 hours. Thank you so much for taking your time to post this, i greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, it's my own, in the sense I haven's seen it before. I'm sure it's known, or is deducible from way more powerful results, among the real analysis mafia. Thanks for your comment.